# Usefulness of KeyEqual in std::unordered_set/std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

I understand that this may be vague question, but I wonder what are real world cases when custom comparator is useful for hash containers in std.
I understand it's usefulness in ordered containers, but for hash containers it seems a bit weird.

Reason for this is that hash value for elements that are equal according to comparator needs to be the same, and I believe that in most cases that actually means converting lookup/insert element to some common representation(it is faster and easier to implement).

For example:

- set of case insensitive strings: if you want to hash properly you need to uppercase/lowercase the entire string anyway.
- set of fractions(where 2/3 == 42/63): you need to convert 42/63 to 2/3 and then hash that...

So I wonder if someone can provide some real world examples of usefulness of customizing `std::unordered_` template parameters so I can recognize those patterns in future code I write.

Note 1: "symmetry argument" (`std::map` enables customization of a comparator so `std::unordred_`should be customizable also) is something I considered and I do not think it is convincing.

Note 2: I mixed 2 kind of comparators (`<` and `==`) in the post for brevity, I know that `std::map` uses `<` and `std::unordered_map` uses `==`.

Comment: One of your claims is wrong. Suppose you store a fraction as a pair of integers, and your hash function for `{a, b}` is `std::hash<float>(static_cast<float>(a)/b)`. Why would `{42, 63}` need to be converted to `{2,3}` before hashing?

Answer (score 10):

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to
>   individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the
>   exact bucket the element is placed into.

So the hash function defines the bucket your element will end up in, but once the bucket is decided, in order to find the element, the `operator ==` will be used.

Basically `operator ==` is used to resolve hash collision, and hence, you need your hash function and your `operator ==` to be consistent. Furthermore, if your operator `operator ==` says that two elements are equal, the set will not allow a duplication.

For what concerns customization, I think that the idea of case-insensitive `set` of `string`s is a good one: given two strings you will need to provide a case-insensitive hash-function to allow the `set` to determine the bucket it has to store the string in. Then you will need to provide a custom `KeyEqual`to allow the set to actually retrieve the element.

A case I had to deal with, in the past, was a way to allow users to insert strings, keeping track of their order of insertion but avoiding duplicates. So, given a struct like:

```
struct keyword{
  std::string value;
  int sequenceCounter;
};
```

You want to detect duplicates according only to `value`. One of the solutions I came up with was an `unordered_set` with a custom comparator/hash function, that used only `value`. This allowed me to check for the existence of a key before allowing insertion.

Answer (score 2):

One interesting usage is to define memory efficient indexes (database sense of the term) for a given set of objects.

## Example

Let's say we have a program that has a collection of `N` objects of this class:

```
struct Person {
    // each object has a unique firstName/lastName pair
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;

    // each object has a unique ssn value
    std::string socialSecurityNumber;

    // each object has a unique email value
    std::string email;
}
```

And we need to retrieve efficiently objects by the value of any unique property.

## Implementations comparison

Time complexities are given assuming string comparisons are constant time (strings have limited length).

#### 1) Single `unordered_map`

With a single `map` indexed by a single key (ex: `email`):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,Person> indexedByEmail;
```

- Time complexity: lookup by any unique property other than `email` requires a traversal of the map: average O(N).
- Memory usage: the `email` value is duplicated. This could be avoided by using a single `set` with custom hash & compare (see 3).

#### 2) Multiple `unordered_map`, no custom hash & compare

With a map for each unique property, with default hash & comparisons:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>, Person> byName;
std::unordered_map<std::string, const Person*> byEmail;
std::unordered_map<std::string, const Person*> bySSN;
```

- Time complexity: by using the appropriate map, a lookup by any unique property is [average O(1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find#Complexity).
- Memory usage: inefficient, because of all the `string` duplications.

#### 3) Multiple `unordered_set`, custom hash & comparison:

With custom hash & comparison, we define different `unordered_set` which will hash & compare only specific fields of the objects. Theses sets can be used to perform lookup as if items were stored in a `map` as in 2, but without duplicating any field.

```
using StrHash = std::hash<std::string>;
// --------------------
struct PersonNameHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Person& p) const {
        // not the best hashing function in the world, but good enough for demo purposes.
        return StrHash()(p.firstName) + StrHash()(p.lastName);
    }
};
struct PersonNameEqual {
    bool operator()(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) const {
        return (p1.firstName == p2.firstName) && (p1.lastName == p2.lastName);
    }
};
std::unordered_set<Person, PersonNameHash, PersonNameEqual> byName;

// --------------------
struct PersonSsnHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Person* p) const {
        return StrHash()(p->socialSecurityNumber);
    }
};
struct PersonSsnEqual {
    bool operator()(const Person* p1, const Person* p2) const {
        return p1->socialSecurityNumber == p2->socialSecurityNumber;
    }
};
std::unordered_set<const Person*, PersonSsnHash, PersonSsnEqual> bySSN;

// --------------------
struct PersonEmailHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Person* p) const {
        return StrHash()(p->email);
    }
};
struct PersonEmailEqual {
    bool operator()(const Person* p1, const Person* p2) const {
        return p1->email == p2->email;
    }
};
std::unordered_set<const Person*,PersonEmailHash,PersonEmailEqual> byEmail;
```

- Time complexity: a lookup by any unique property is still O(1) average.
- Memory usage: much better than 2): no `string` duplication.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SkzlNafzH7vX1uql)

Answer (score -1):

The hash function itself does something to extract features in a certain way, and The comparator's job is to distinguish whether features are the same or not
With a "shell" of data you may not need to modify the comparator
Briefly: put a feature shell on the data. Features are responsible for being compared

As a matter of fact, I don't quite understand what you problem description. My speech is inevitably confused in logic. Please understand.
:)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Maybe you should explain what you mean, instead of inventing a meaning for "shell" and expecting everyone else to comprehend what you have not written? Also, that last paragraph basically says that you answered without understanding the question; that rarely works out well.